# Controls on bootstrap are too tall

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootwatch css http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ for bootstrap

When I use the template on a large screen, the components are too tall

http://jsfiddle.net/o37rak4k/1/

[image: layout problem]

I imagine I don't use it well. How can I resolve that issue ? I need to have control at the "normal" size (a bit more than the text size)

My html code :

```
<div class="container">
     <h2>
        Liste des interventions
    </h2>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="contenu_DdlClients">Client :</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select name="ctl00$contenu$DdlClients" id="contenu_DdlClients" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0"></option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Planification de :</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                        <input name="ctl00$contenu$dateDebPlanification" type="text" id="contenu_dateDebPlanification" class="form-control hasDatepicker" style="width:130px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></span>
 <span id="contenu_RgDateDebut" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">à :</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                        <input name="ctl00$contenu$dateFinPlanification" type="text" id="contenu_dateFinPlanification" class="form-control hasDatepicker" style="width:130px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></span>
 <span id="contenu_RgDateFin" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change the line-height or height in the `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.css` file as it is the standard for bootstrap `class="form-control"`.

Alternatively you can override it in the page (which would not be ideal - rather in the css)

```
.form-control {height:16px;}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/o37rak4k/2/)

for the calendar image use the following example:

[JSFIDDLE DEMO for Calendar Glyphicon](http://jsfiddle.net/o37rak4k/3/) - Have a look at the code. I added  and example different from the original code.

Remember to use the `class="col-...."` (using the [**GRID**](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)) to specify the width and not an actual width setting for the input or else the calendar image will not sit next to the input box and also not resize properly.

**[Horizontal form spacing and label alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/o37rak4k/4/)** - Form layout is horizontal and label align with the input

Comment: well it's really better but the different line have different size. is it possible to improve that ? moreover is it possible to put the calendar icon in the right of the textbox ? tks a lot

Comment: tks again, the cal is fine and I will remove the width attribute. but is it possible to have equal space between each line ? what is the problem actually ? I just want something like : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/address-details-modal-form